# Spring said that a bean already exist but this bean was just moved to another folder

Tags: java, spring

I just moved some files in my project and spring boot won't run

```
.
├── DatabaseLoader.java
├── HomeController.java
├── product
│   ├── Product.java
│   └── ProductRepository.java
├── security
│   ├── JWTAuthenticationFilter.java
│   ├── JWTAuthorizationFilter.java
│   ├── SecurityConstants.java
│   └── WebSecurity.java
├── ShopApplication.java
└── user
    ├── ApplicationUser.java
    ├── ApplicationUserRepository.java
    ├── UserController.java
    └── UserDetailsServiceImpl.java
```

Is it because controllers should were in the same folder as ShopApplication (@SpringBootApplication) ?

Spring shows this description:

```
The bean 'productRepository', defined in com.ecommerce.shop.product.ProductRepository defined in
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration,
could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in 
com.ecommerce.shop.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration and overriding is disabled.
```

If it is not enough information you can checkout my github repository [here](https://github.com/KacperKromka/e-commerce)

I would be very grateful for any attention. Thank you!

Comment: You moved it, didn't clean the project and simply restarted. The old class file is still there. Clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may be used `@EnableJpaRepositories` multiple times. In your repository classes just annotating them with  `@Repository` would be enough.

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Putting `@Repository` on there yields nothing. Putting it on an interface is pretty much useless. Spring Data detects them in other ways and component-scanning will ignore them.